# Oracle ADF - Menus

Tags: css, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We developed a Oracle ADF web app using

- jDeveloper 11.1.2.4

The following is our menu style

[image]

Observe Add KPI, Update KPI and Delete KPI. This is a simple menu list. We need to improve Look and Feel of this menu list.How to make it stylish. Like as follows .

[image]

Please help us.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you also post some of the code snippets you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy to do, but to do it you might need some understanding of CSS Stylesheets.

You should start by creating your own ADF Skin in Jdeveloper and use the excellent ADF Skin Editor for changing the look and feel of your component.

Comment: Hi florinmarcus. I tried some skinning technicques in JDeveloper. I created a new skin. And in that Faces Component Selectors I have af|menu. In property Inspector which property I have to change, can you please tell me where I have to do changes.

Comment: @Abdul That's indeed the hard part (figuring out what selectors you need to style). The easiest way is to disable the CSS compression (that way, you can see the real ID's and classes in the source) and use the developer tools of Chrome or Firefox to find the components/selectors you need to style.

Comment: You should do some studying on ADF Skinning concepts and then you will be able to customize your look and feel pretty easily.   User404 gave you a good tip on how to start investigating the af menu skin selectors.  You can't posibly expect that someone from over here to do this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using af|menu selectors you can style it. Here is a sample

https://coderoar.blogspot.com/2018/08/oracle-adf-menu-skinning.html